# How to analyze stack trace of native frames (fatal error log)

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

When I analyze Java hot spot error log (hs_err_pid..).
I don't know how to analyze 'Native Frames' in Thread Stack section.

[Sample Log]

```
...
Stack: [0x00007f011b4c7000,0x00007f011b5c8000],  sp=0x00007f011b5c5050,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

J 10454 C2 java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object; (300 bytes) @ 0x00007f0182a91ac5 [0x00007f0182a91a00+0xc5]
...
```

Can you explain what is `10454`, `C2`, `java.util.HashMap.putVal(ILjava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ZZ)Ljava/lang/Object;`, `(300 bytes)`, `@`, `0x00007f0182a91ac5`, `[0x00007f0182a91a00+0xc5]`?